# What is happenening with adjacent divs that causes them to separate?

Tags: html, css

And why is there no way to style this behavior away other than to compromise and otherwise consistent indentation scheme in the HTML?

```css
.adjacent {

 display: inline-block;
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="adjacent">Hello</div><!--sweet-->
<div class="adjacent">world</div><!--sweet-->
<br /><br />
<div class="adjacent">Hello</div><!--ugh--><div class="adjacent">
&nbsp world</div>
```

Comment: I think this answer might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'll use the comment method, because that allows me to keep my indentation scheme intact.